# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException on mockmvc post

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mime-types, mockmvc

I have a RestController and a function that accepts post requests

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/auth",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws  IOException {
}
```

I try to issue a post request

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/auth")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content("{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"fruit\": \"apple\" }".getBytes()))
            .andDo(print());
```

I receive

```
Resolved Exception:
         Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException
```

Any workaround ideas?

Edit: I also tried specifying the consumes="application/json" on the controller, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception says that the "media type" aka "content type" is not accepted.

Try adding *consumes = "application/json"* to your controller function.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/auth",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public void authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws  IOException {
}
```

See the spring documentation for details https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--

Comment: Maybe you can provide the whole exception with some more context?